# why does not Drag and Drop work in this situation?

Tags: robotframework

I'm using  Drag and Drop in Robot Framework but I have an error :Keyword 'Drag And Drop' expected 0 arguments, got 2
this is my script:

Drag And Drop

```
Click link     //*[@id="HEADER_ADMIN_CONSOLE_text"]/a
sleep     2
Click Element    //a[@title="Gestionnaire de modèles"]
sleep   2
Click Element    //span[text()="${vModel}"]
sleep    2
Click Element    //span[text()="${Type personnalise}"]/ancestor::tr//span[text()='Actions']
sleep    2
Click Element    //span[text()="${Type personnalise}"]/ancestor::body//div[@role='region']//tr[@title='Concepteur de disposition']
sleep    2
Drag And Drop    //*[@id='dojoUnique1']   //div[@id='FORM_CANVAS']
sleep   2
```

And if I put the two variables in Arguments the error message will not be displayed but the script will click again on the two first buttons then stops
do you have an idea ??

this is my log's message

```
Tester                                                                | FAIL| 
Keyword 'Drag And Drop' expected 0 arguments, got 2.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Log4J.DragAndDrop                                                     | FAIL|
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed 1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
=============================================================================
```

Comment: What kind of Drag and Drop keyword is it?

Comment: By any chance did you forgot to save? And are you sure about the error? Make sure you copied it from logs

Comment: The provided code example is incomplete. This means we have no idea which library is used, and if there are any conflicting keywords. Nor have a means to replicate the results, which often is the starting point to provide a working answer.